# Determine degree of polynomial given as black box

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

Polynomial with the natural coefficients is given as a black box (you can choose any $p>0$ and evaluate it in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in time $O(\log(p))$)
Moreover, we know that the degree of black box polynomial is bounded by n.

Can we determine the degree of polynomial in randomized time $o(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

We can take values
$$P_0(i)=P(i), i=0\dots n,$$
and to calculate differences
$$P_k(j)=P_{k-1}(j+1)-P_{k-1}(j), j=0\dots n-k-1$$
until all $P_k(j)$ became constants.

It is easy to prove that all $P_k=const$ for $k$th order polynomial.

Comment: Yes, of course. This approach was first presented by R. Liebling. Similar solutions has been given by Kaltofen and Tragen in 1990. But still, in the worst case it is $O(n)$. The question was if something sublinear $o(n)$, (e.g., $O(n^{0.99})$) can be done.

Comment: @Adam Then specify the real question

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov  Does this method work for multivariant boolean polynomial? Can you please take a look into this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/423634/determine-degree-of-boolean-polynomial-given-as-black-box